# Calculator, using python, 0 used 1st, it never recognizes the second input to calculate.

Tags: python, input, printing, calculator, solver

```
print("1: ADDITION")
print("2: SUBTRACTION")
print("3: MULTIPLICATION")
print("4: DIVISION")

CHOICE = input("Enter the Numbers:")

if CHOICE == "1":
num1 =(input("Enter the value of num1:"))

    if num1=="0": #if 0 is used
    print ("Invalid Number")
    if num1 =="0": #if 0 is used
        input("Enter the value of num1:") #Enter number,0 used to get error
    if num1 !="0":
        print (num1)
    num2 =(input("Enter the value of num2:"))
    if num2=="0": #if 0 is used.
        print ("Invalid Number")
    if num2 =="0": #if 0 is used.
        input ("Enter the value of num2:") #Enter number,0 used to get error
    if num2 !="0":`enter code here`
        print (num2)
    value = float(num1) + float (num2) #this only solves for 1st input   
    print ("The sum of each num1 added to each num2:" + str(value))
```

I was trying to use this as a calculator to initially cause the error, then input the correct info on the second attempt. This never recognizes the second attempt info. It only picks up the first info for num1 and num2. How can I have this recognize the second input which is the numbers that need to get added?

Comment: Something went wrong with your code formatting. This code crashes on my machine with an IndendationError. Consult [Markdown help - Code and Preformatted Text](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) and [edit] your post.

Comment: You forgot to assign the input to a variable. Change `input("Enter the value of num1:")` to `num1 = input("Enter the value of num1:")`.

Comment: No indent after some if.
If you only enter number, then compare with number,  not string.
Edit your text to be readable and explicit.

Comment: I made the adjustment and still get the same result I was getting before, it produces 0.0. I'm using 0 first to cause the error but it never recognizes the numbers I put in the second time.

Comment: Aran-Fay answered your question. After 3rd if, you don't input to a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach is to use a `while` loop to collect input, and only exit the `while` loop after receiving valid data.

```
num1 = 0
while num1 == 0:
    value = input(....
    if ValidateInput(value):
        num1 = value
num2 = 0
while num2 == 0:
    value = input(....
    if ValidateInput(value):
        num2 = value
# do other stuff

def ValidateInput(input):
    """Common code that ensures the input is a numerical value, etc"""
```